# definition of reserved, terminal and normized URLs

Tags: html, url, web

I came across the following types of URLS. Are these types usually used in the web community? It's the first time that I encouter them and I couldn't find any definition on the web.

**Terminal**

```
http://www.krmg.com/photo/ap/entertainment/donald-trump-among-next-weeks-guests-on-the-tonigh/pCp2Yk/
```

**Reversed**

```
com.krmg/photo/ap/entertainment/donald-trump-among-next-weeks-guests-on-the-tonigh/pCp2Yk/
```

**Normalized**

```
http://krmg.com/photo/ap/entertainment/donald-trump-among-next-weeks-guests-on-the-tonigh/pCp2Yk/
```

---

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization

Comment: "It's the first time that I encouter them and I couldn't find any definition on the web." — Where did you encounter them then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserved url can be defined as "URLs for Reporting Services applications are defined as reserved URL in HTTP.SYS. A URL reservation defines the syntax of a URL endpoint to a Web application. URL reservations are defined for both the Report Server Web service and Report Manager when you configure the applications on the report server. URL reservations are created for you automatically when configure URLs through Setup or the Reporting Services Configuration tool".

Normalized Url - Normalized URL which is also known as canonicalization URL, is the process of choosing the best URL from available ones.URL normalization is a major step in Search engine optimization as search engines employ URL normalization in order to assign importance to web pages and to reduce indexing of same pages again which can cause duplicate content, even a web browser may perform normalization to determine if a link has been visited or to check if a page has been cached.

Terminal url  I dont have proper definition.

Answer (score 2):

Terminal url can be define as a point at which a signal enters and/or leaves a network.